# I cannot make code run that shows error is like Using $this when not in object context?

Tags: php

```
<?php class DB{

public static $conn;

public function __construct(){
    try {
        $this->conn = new \PDO( 'mysql:host=' . Route::get('mysql/host') . '; dbname='. Route::get('mysql/db'), Route::get('mysql/username'), Route::get('mysql/password') );
        $this->conn->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $this->conn;

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die('Sorry cannot connect!');
    }
}

public function __destruct(){
    $this->conn->close();
    unset($this->conn);
}

public static function db_query($query, $bindings){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($bindings);
    $res = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $res ? $res : false;
}
```

}

?>
problem is how can i pass the connection to another function to avoid errors like above. please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `$this` in static function. This is quote from [PHP manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php):

> The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).

You can change `db_query()` to non-static and call it like `$db->db_query()` instead of `DB::db_query()`